# How to display UITextField one by one in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

UIKit. For example, I have five textfields in my app. All in one ViewController. When I launch my app all these textfields appears simultaneously on the view.

So, I would like to make next changes:

1. Launching App -> User sees first textfield -> Tap on it, enter info -> tap something (like button or just finish editing first textfield, doesn't matter) ->
2. Second textfield appears on the view, after the first textfield. <..> ->
3. Third textfield appears on the view <..> ->
4. Fourth textfield appears on the view. <..> ->
5. Fifth textfield appears on the view.

Plus I would like to use animation to get the smooth appearing effect (it's a different story, meantime).

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the textfield to a UIStackView.
2. Hide all but the first textfields using `isHidden = true`
3. Set the view controller to be the delegate of all text fields.
4. Override one of the relevant delegate methods to get notified when editing finishes. Which one depends on what you want to do and when editing finishes.
5. Set `isHidden = false` for the text field that should appear within an animation block. Use UIView-based animation or UIViewPropertyAnimator.

If one of the points is unclear, you are not ready yet to build this. Read, read and experiment until these points become clear. Then implement them.